# I want to pass 'Filename' as argument to other function call but always it is returning 'None' as value

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I m developing GUI using PyQT4: Code looks like below -

```
def fileopening(): 
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(mainwindow, 'Select file') 
    print(filename) 
    return filename


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_mainwindow()
    ui.setupUi(mainwindow)
    filename = ui.browser.clicked.connect(fileopening)
    print(filename)
    ui.progressBar.setValue(100)
    ui.progesslabel.setText('Kindly fill in the fields and proceed for splitting.')
    ui.splitbutton.clicked.connect(pressed)
    ui.resetparameter.clicked.connect(reset)

    mainwindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

When UI is prompted it gives print output as 'None' and from defination of function it gets filename in function call but it is not returning any value. Can anybody suggest what may be the possible reason? I want to pass 'Filename' as argument to other function call but always it is returning 'None' as value.

Comment: What is `fileopening` exactly ?

Comment: def fileopening():
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(mainwindow, 'Select file') 
    print(filename)
    return filename

Comment: fileopening is a function to get file name from QFileDialog.. as mentioned above.. @scherette

Comment: I know but your filename is always `None`. Therefore the problem is probably there.

Comment: What are your print statements returning ?

Comment: Once I select any file from QFileDialog object than it is returning Windows file name of selected file. It is getting printed from function but the same value is not being returned from function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAve you tried

```
return QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(mainwindow, 'Select file')
```

You can make the name filename global.

```
def fileopening(): 
    global filename
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(mainwindow, 'Select file')
```

Comment: Ya ... I tried still it is giving 'None' as return value. Is it something related to button clicked event and main function?